# Oracle Execute immediate JSON path expression syntax error

Tags: oracle, json-value

I want to loop through a Json string to retrieve values. The following code gives me a
JSON path expression error.

```
declare 
buffer clob;
  pos number;
  Numb number; 
begin
  pos := 1;
  buffer := '{"root":[{"theData":[224.08755140452405,124.08755140452405,324.08755140452405]}]}';
  pos := 0; 
  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select json_value(buffer,''$.root[0].theData[:pos]'') from dual'
  using pos
  returning INTO numb;
  dbms_output.put_line(numb);
  
end;
```

If I replace the execute immediate command with the following  statement

```
select json_value(buffer,'$.root[0].theData[0]') into numb from dual;
```

it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `buffer` supposed to be in the dynamic version? Did you mean to bind that and pass the real value via `using` too? (Presumably you do actually have a reason to do this dynamically...?)

Answer (score 2):

If you [check out the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56668), they mention that the JSON path expression has to be a *string literal* - so it can't include a bind variable or substitution variable.

But since you're running it with `execute immediate`, you can make it appear to be a literal when the string is executed as a query. I think you want something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select json_value(:buffer,''$.root[0].theData[' || pos || ']'') from dual'
into numb
using buffer;
```

Edit: also corrected the syntax

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using SQL, you can use [PL/SQL Object types for JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.html#GUID-F0561593-D0B9-44EA-9C8C-ACB6AA9474EE):

```sql
declare 
  buffer clob := '{"root":[{"theData":[224.08755140452405,124.08755140452405,324.08755140452405]}]}';
  pos    PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  Numb   number;
  json_arr JSON_ARRAY_T;
begin
  json_arr := TREAT(
                JSON_OBJECT_T( buffer ).get_array('root').get(0)
                AS JSON_OBJECT_T
              ).get_array('theData');

  FOR pos IN 0 .. json_arr.get_size() - 1 LOOP
    numb := json_arr.get_number(pos);
    dbms_output.put_line(numb);
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 224.08755140452405
> 124.08755140452405
> 324.08755140452405
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7894e09e6c87a28b69e219ee68a209ed)*